# Determinant of $P_n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I am preparing for an exam on linear algebra within few days, so I am in desperate need for a solution for the following question:

**Question:**

Let $P_n$, $n\ge2$, be the $n\times n$ matrix whose entries are all $1's$, except for $0's$ directly below the main diagonal.

For instance $P_3=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\0&1&1\\1&0&1\end{bmatrix}$ and $P_4=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1\\0&1&1&1\\1&0&1&1\\1&1&0&1\end{bmatrix}$.

Find the determinant of $P_n$.

---

**My attempt**

Note that $P_{n-1}$ is the minor of the entry $[a_{11}]$ of $P_n$.

By observation, one could conjecture that $det(P_n)=1$ as all the cofactors vanish. (I've tried $P_2$ to $P_5$ and it seems valid.)

**So is there a formal way to proof such cofactors sum up to zero?**

Comment: Did you try to add to the first column all the $n-1$ others ? You will end with the first coefficient equals to $n$ and all the other ones in the first column equal to $n-1$. So after some substractions, you can have the vector $(n,n-1,0,\ldots,0)^T$ in the first column and lots of $0$ in the matrix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $A_{i,j}$ denote the matrix one gets by removing the $i$th row and $j$th column from $P_n$.
Then expanding $\det P_n$ along the first column gives you
$$\det{P_n} = \sum_{j=1}^{n} (-1)^{j+1}a_{j,1} \det A_{j,1}$$
As you noticed $A_{1,1} = P_{n-1}$. It is also given that $a_{1,1} = 1$ and $a_{2,1} = 0$.

For $j>2$, the first two rows of $A_{j,1}$ are equal, therefore $\det A_{j,1} = 0$.
So you can conclude that $$\det P_n = \det P_{n-1}$$
Finally use that $\det P_2 = 1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I get it. So should I add: Observe that the entries of the first row and second row, except for $a_{11}$ and $a_{21}$, are the same, so the value of the all cofactors other than that of  $a_{11}$ are zero, which results in $det{P_n}=det(P_{n-1})$.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was thinking.

Comment: Thank you once again:).

Comment: Sure thing! :-)